# How to read numbers from a text file properly?

Tags: c, file, text

I would like to write a lottery program in C, that reads the chosen numbers of former weeks into an array. I have got a text file in which there are 5 columns that are separated with tabulators. My questions would be the following:

- What should I separate the columns with? (e.g. a comma, a semicolon, a tabulator or something else)
- Should I include a kind of EOF in the last row? (e.g. -1, "EOF") Is there any accepted or "official" convention to do this?
- Which function should I use for reading the numbers? Is there any proper or "accepted" way of reading data from text files?

I used to write a C program for a "Who Wants to Be a Billionaire" game. In that one I used a kind of function that read each line into an array that was big enough to hold a whole line. After that I separated its data into variables like this:

```
line: "text1";"text2";"text3";"text4"endline (-> line loaded into a buffer array)
text1 -> answer1 (until reaching the semicolon)
text2 -> answer2 (until reaching the semicolon)
text3 -> answer3 (until reaching the semicolon)
text4 -> answer4 (until reaching the end of the line)
endline -> start over, that is read a new line and separate its contents into variables.
```

It worked properly, but I don't know if it was good enough for a programmer. (btw I'm not a programmer yet, I study Computer Science at a university)

Every answers and advice is welcome. Thanks in advance for your kind help!

Comment: Although 'tabulators' was the basis for 'tabs' and Unicode defines U+0009 HORIZONTAL TABULATION and U+000B VERTICAL TABULATION, most people will write 'tabs' or 'tab stops' rather than 'tabulators' or 'tabulation' (using 'vertical tab' for U+000B).

Comment: colons `:` or semicolons `;`  make excellent delimiters for numeric data.  Suggest not using `tabs`  as they tend to make the data more difficult for human reading as they are not necessarily easily visible when looking at a text file.  Strongly suggest each group of numbers be separated via a newline `\n'` because then can read the whole line using a call to `fgets()` and parse the line, in memory, using `sscanf()` or `strtok()`

Answer (score 3):

The `scanf()` family of functions don't care about newlines, so if you want to process lines, you need to read the lines first and then process the lines with `sscanf()`.  The `scanf()` family of functions also treats white space — blanks, tabs, newlines, etc. — interchangeably.  Using tabs as separators is fine, but blanks will work too.  Clearly, if you're reading and processing a line at a time, newlines won't really factor into the scanning.

```
int lottery[100][5];
int line;
char buffer[4096];

for (line = 0; fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != 0 && line < 100; line++)
{
    if (sscanf(buffer, "%d %d %d %d %d", &lottery[line][0], &lottery[line][1],
               &lottery[line][2], &lottery[line][3], &lottery[line][4]) != 5)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Faulty line: [%s]\n", line);
        break;
    }
}
```

This stops on EOF, too many lines, and a faulty line (one which doesn't start with 5 numbers; you can check their values etc in the loop if you want to — but what are the tests you need to run?). If you want to validate the white space separators, you have to work harder.

Maybe you want to test for nothing but spaces and newlines after the 5 numbers; that's a bit trickier (it can be done; look up the `%n` conversion specification in [`sscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sscanf.html)).

Comment: Minor: Suggest `line < 100 && fgets(buffer, ...` as not to read and throw away input  after 100 lines..

Comment: @chux: Interesting point.  It might depend on whether there are supposed to be exactly 100 lines in the file (standard input); if that's the case, as written it gets to EOF before checking whether there's space.  If you don't mind there being more data to read, then your right that checking the index first would be better.  As you said 'minor', and you can make an argument either way — in retrospect, check index before input is probably the better general arrangement.